# Categorizing a data based on string in each row

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 raw_data = {'name': ['Willard', 'Nan', 'Omar', 'Spencer'],
'Last_Name': ['Smith', 'Nan', 'Sheng', 'Poursafar'],
'favorite_color': ['blue', 'red', 'Nan', "green"],
'Statues': ['Match', 'Mis-Match', 'Match', 'Mis_match']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['name', 'age', 'favorite_color', 'grade'])
df
```

I wanna do the following tasks:

1. Separate the rows that contain Match and Mis-match
2. Make a category that only contains people whose first name and last name are Nan and love a color(any color except for nan).

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Statues'] == 'Match']
df2 = df[df['Statues'] =='Mis-Match']
```

If missing values are not strings use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and 
[`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df3 = df[df['Name'].isna() & df['Last_NameName'].isna() & df['favorite_color'].notna()]
```

If `Nan`s are strings compare by `Nan`:

```
df3 = df[(df['Name'] == 'Nan') & 
         (df['Last_NameName'] == 'Nan') &
         (df['favorite_color'] != 'Nan')]
```

Comment: Any reason to use `df['col'].notna()` versus `!df['col'].isna()` ? +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - It is not valid code, need `~df['col'].isna()`, but simplier is `df['favorite_color'].notna()`

Comment: @Sam - No, only normal guy from Slovakia ;)